# add values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an invoice in which i want to add more values to quantity field from another text field. 
I am trying with the code given bellow it's calculating all the rows in invoice instead of a specific row.
Your suggestions are highly valuable.

***main.js***  _______________________________________________________________________________

```
function Invoice(ID = null) {

if (ID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            ID: ID
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            response.result.forEach(function(element) {
                console.log(element);
                var item = element.item;
                var qty = element.qty;
                var price = element.price;
                var total = element.qty * element.price;

                var i = $('table tr').length;

                html = '<tr>';
                html += '<td><input type="number" id="add_' + i + '" class="add"></td>';

                html += '<td><input type="text" value="' + item + '" id="item_' + i + '"></td>';

                html += '<td><input type="number" value="' + qty + '" id="QTY_' + i + '" ></td>';

                html += '<td><input type="number" value="' + price + '" id="PRICE_' + i + '"b></td>';

                html += '<td><input type="number" value="' + total + '" id="Total_' + i + '" class="inLinePrice" ></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
                $('table').append(html);
                i++;

                calculate();


                $(document).on('change keyup blur', '.add', function() {
                    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
                    id = id_arr.split("_");
                    add = $('#add_' + id[1]).val();
                    Qty = $('#QTY_' + id[1]).val();
                    if (add != '' && typeof(add) != "undefined") {
                        added = parseFloat(Qty) + parseFloat(add);
                        $('#QTY_' + id[1]).val(added);
                        priceAfter = $('#PRICE_' + id[1]).val();
                        $('#Total_' + id[1]).val((parseFloat(priceAfter) * parseFloat(added)).toFixed(2));
                        calculate();

                    } else {
                        $('#QTY_' + id[1]).val(qty);
                        $('#Total_' + id[1]).val((parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty)).toFixed(2));
                        calculate();
                    }
                });

            });

        }
    });
} else {
    alert('error');
}
}



//total calculation 
function calculate() {
    subTotal = 0;
    total = 0;
    $('.inLinePrice').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') subTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
$('#subTotal').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));

}
```

[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmOoH.png)

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auvd4dge/13/) that demonstrates your code. The only thing I fixed was changing the `Qty`variable to `qty` (there was a mixed usage of `Qty` and `qty`). Can you please explain how it behaves wrongly, and what it should do instead?

Comment: thanks @ Anders Carstensen for your time. You just repeated qty variable twice Because qty variable  once mentioned above. thats why the result is same as above and else function is not working also.

Comment: You need to describe more precisely the behavior you are expecting. Example: "When I write 2 in the Add field in the first row, I expect 2 to be added to the quantity and the Add field should be cleared."

Comment: this is edit invoice page. when i load this page it should fetch quantity from database.if current quantity is 1 and i add 1 more it should be 2, else quantity should remain same as fetched from database

Comment: I updated the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/auvd4dge/17/). I made [a video](https://i.imgur.com/swDc4nT.gifv) where I write a number in Add field and it updates the Quantity field. Please explain what you think is **not** working in this example.

Comment: exactly i need this video example . But why it's not working in **jsfiddle**.

Comment: when i click outside of the text field it changes quantity.

Comment: Yes, that's what your original code dictates: `on('change keyup blur')` - the `change` and `blur` events typically happens when the text field loses focus. I removed `keyup` in my example because it makes it impossible to write more than one digit.

Comment: what kind of changes you made in my code. i am trying it from an hour. it's still not working fine.

Comment: i am trying your provided code in above given situation.

Comment: else function is very important which is not working in **jsfiddle**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove change and blur from `on('change keyup blur')` to `on('keyup')` and check it.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.add', function () {
id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
id = id_arr.split("_");
add = $('#add_' + id[1]).val();
qty = $('#QTY_' + id[1]).val();
if (add != '' && typeof (add) != "undefined") {
  $('#add_' + id[1]).val('');
  added = parseFloat(qty) + parseFloat(add);
  $('#QTY_' + id[1]).val(added);
  priceAfter = $('#PRICE_' + id[1]).val();
  $('#Total_' + id[1]).val((parseFloat(priceAfter) * parseFloat(added)).toFixed(2));
  calculate();

} else {
  $('#QTY_' + id[1]).val(qty);
  $('#Total_' + id[1]).val((parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty)).toFixed(2));
  calculate();
}
});

});
```

Comment: thanks i did a month before .But thanks for you time.